# Upload Excel file to Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

authcookie = Office365('https://********.sharepoint.com/', username='dhruvpanchal@******.onmicrosoft.com', password='********').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/BorakayInternal', version=Version.v2019, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/This Folder')
folder.upload_folder('ConsolidatedTimesheet.xlsx')
```

In this code i get error :-

```
folder.upload_folder('ConsolidatedTimesheet.xlsx')
AttributeError: '_Folder' object has no attribute 'upload_folder'
```

Can anyone help me solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you specified a file as the parameter while the function is 'upload_folder'. I check the official docs of [shareplum](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html), should it be the following method?

[image]

Comment: no, this is the method to upload text file, I am not able to to upload excel file using this.

Comment: For non-text file, you can get its binary content then upload it. with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent = file.read()
folder.upload_file(fileContent, "filename.bin")